# spring mvc3 map root url

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I quite new to spring mvc3. My question is that when I host my application, 'myApp', on tomcat , the base url is `http://localhost:8080/myApp/...`

I want to know that how is it possible for me in my application to have '/' being mapped to 'myApp' automatically. So that I don't have to add my application's name in my code.

Thanks

Comment: deploy your application as ROOT

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the tomcat instance's server.xml, go to the `<Context>` definition corresponding to your name and set the `path` attribute to empty string "".